# "this" (object) is undefined when calling angularjs function with $timeout

Tags: angularjs, service, this

I have an angular service to manage my on screen alerts:

```
angular.module('theapp')
.factory('Alerts', function ($timeout) {

  var unsetMsg = null;

  return {

    alertType: null,
    alertTitle: null,
    alertMessage: null,

    setMessage: function(type, title, message, timed) {     
        var self = this;
        $timeout.cancel(unsetMsg);
        self.alertType = type;
        self.alertTitle = title;
        self.alertMessage = message;

        if (timed)
        {
            unsetMsg = $timeout(self.unsetMessage,5000);
        }
    },

    unsetMessage: function() {
        this.alertType = null;
        this.alertTitle = null;
        this.alertMessage = null;   
        $timeout.cancel(unsetMsg);
    }
  }
  });
```

Setting the message works fine (called from an angular controller) and sets the timeout variable OK, but when the function called within the timeout (unsetMessage) runs after the 5 second delay, the code throws an error `this is undefined`.  Why would it not recognise itself as an object and how do I achieve what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One possibility is to use the captured `self` and [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) it on the callback so that the proper context is being passed:

```
if (timed) {
    unsetMsg = $timeout(function() {
        self.unsetMessage.apply(self);
    }, 5000);
}
```